# When will the third radius be an integer?

Tags: geometry

I'm working on a problem dealing with three tangent circles and a line. I'm given the radius of two of the circles and I know that the radius of the third circle is
$$r_3 = {r_1r_2\over (\sqrt{r_1}+\sqrt{r_2})^2}$$. Given that the first two radii are integers, when will the third also be an integer?

Comment: First think about what property the denominator need to have to make $r_3$ a rational number, and then think about what further restrictions you need to have to make it an integer. HINT: Expand the denominator

Answer (score 1):

You are asking when $r_3=\frac {r_1r_2}{(\sqrt {r_1} + \sqrt {r_2})^2}=\frac {r_1r_2}{r_1+2\sqrt {r_1r_2}+r_2}$ is an integer.  Let $m=\gcd (r_1,r_2)$.  To make the square root an integer, we must have $r_1=mp^2, r_2=mq^2$, with $p,q$ coprime, giving $r_3=\frac {m^2p^2q^q}{mp^2+2mpq+mq^2}=\frac {mp^2q^2}{p^2+2pq+q^2}=\frac {m(pq)^2}{(p+q)^2}$  Since $p+q$ is coprime to $p,q$, we must have $(p+q)^2|m$.  One example would be $p=1,q=2,m=9$, giving $r_1=9,r_2=36, r_3=4$